# Reuse the authentication of the user against LDAP in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis, amq

LDAP authentication is configured in ActiveMQ Artemis(2.6.1 -Redhat AMQ7.2) environment but i am noticing authentication for a user happens against LDAP server very frequently. Even when no messages received, seems the authentication is happening.

Attempted increasing `security-invalidation-interval` but doesn't take that into account.

I noticed this behavior by turning on logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `security-invalidation-interval` applies to *authorization* but not to authentication. Authentication always hits whatever is providing the account information (in this case LDAP).

Comment: got it..we noticed the below failures. Sometime it comes either because of Too many open files or Socket connection closed  and suspected it might be due to frequent connections.                                                                                            
AMQ224084: Failed to open context: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed

Comment: Support for connection pooling was added for the `LDAPLoginModule` in Artemis 2.6.3. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1971. Therefore, if you're running out of file handles due to too many LDAP connections then you should be able to upgrade and resolve that problem.